# iis arr proxy route to a scalable azure VM farm

Tags: azure, iaas

We have a third party product run as a windows service, expose as a web service. The goal is to dynamically provision the service instances in business peak hours.

Just to run the thought with you guys,
- I've already deployed the service on multiple vm, configured the vm in the same cloud service Availability Sets, configured azure to turn on/off vm instances based on cpu use
- I am to configure a separate vm, run iss arr there, add points to the endpoints on the vm configured above, with the hope ARR balanced the requests to the back-end vm dynamically

Will this work? What's the best practice for the IaaS scale? Any thoughts? Truly appreciate the input.

Comment: why use arr instead of cloud service load balance set?

Comment: Thanks. Could you please help point some direction. Will it work with auto scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you just need to use the built in load balancer of the cloud service. Create a load balance set for your endpoint. For example, if you want to balace the incoming traffic to port 80 in your application all you have to do is to create a LB-set for this port and configure this set to all the VMs in the Cloud Service.

> The Azure Load Balancer randomly distributes a specific type of
>   incoming traffic across multiple virtual machines or services in a
>   configuration known as a load-balanced set. For example, you can
>   spread the load of web request traffic across multiple web servers or
>   web roles.

[Configure a load-balanced set](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-internet-getstarted/)

[Azure load balancing for virtual machines](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-load-balance/)

No matter if VMs are up or down, once it turns on and if the endpoint is configured in the same LB-set, it will automatically start responding to requests once port 80 is online (IIS started and is returning STATUS 200 OK, for example). So, answering your question: yes, it will work with auto-scale or manuallying turning on/off vms.

Comment: thanks, took a read, it seems the load balanced set offers comparably basic features with IIS ARR. We look for support of url-rewrite, ssl offloading, port re-directing, it seems to me i am left with IIS ARR on VM approach. Hope there is a 'ARR as service' in future